# FirebaseAnalytics logEvent by creating a new instance each time in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I'm adding Google Analytics to my Flutter project.
Is it OK to log events in a static function like this?

```
static Future<void> logEvent(String eventName) async {
  await FirebaseAnalytics().logEvent(name: eventName);
}
```

FirebaseAnalytics is initialized each time the function is called.
Will this cause problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not cause any problems except a small overhead, but it's nice to have it as a singleton. Eg., later you might realize that it makes sense to wrap the analytics reporting with some custom logic and you don't want to copy it around. `InheritedWidget` helps to get the same object instance from anywhere down the tree.

```
class Analytics extends InheritedWidget {
 final FirebaseAnalytics _analytics;

  Analytics(this._analytics, Widget child) : super(child: child);

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(Analytics oldWidget) {
    return _analytics != oldWidget._analytics;
  }

  static FirebaseAnalytics of(BuildContext context) {
    final provider =
        (context.getElementForInheritedWidgetOfExactType<Analytics>()?.widget) as Analytics;

    assert(provider != null);

    return provider._analytics;
  }
}
```

Put it on op of the widget tree when you build your app:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics();
    var firebaseAnalyticsObserver = FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(
      analytics: analytics,
    );
    return Analytics(
      analytics,
      MaterialApp(
        navigatorObservers: [
          firebaseAnalyticsObserver,
        ],
        ...
```

Access it from any widget that's lower down the tree:

```
Analytics.of(context).logEvent(name: "my_custom_event");
```